# Decimals in Query formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to make a query formula.

```
=QUERY(namedRange;"SELECT F WHERE 2.6 > D AND 2.6 < E")
```

This works, but when I'm using a column reference like E7 it doesn't work.
The value in E7 is 2,6. I know the comma breaks the query..

```
=QUERY(namedRange;"SELECT F WHERE '"&E7&"' > D AND '"&E7&"' < E")
```

So i replace the comma with `=SUBSTITUTE(E7;",";".";1)`

```
=QUERY(namedRange;"SELECT F WHERE '"&SUBSTITUTE(E7;",";".";1)&"' > D AND '"&SUBSTITUTE(E7; ","; "."; 1)&"' < E")
```

Still no luck...

I hope some with more understanding of this can help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrapping stuff in `QUERY` into single quotes converts it into a text string so it's the same as you would try to math out if `"abc > 123"` - it does not make any sense...

try:

```
=QUERY(namedRange; 
 "select F 
  where "&SUBSTITUTE(E7; ","; "."; 1)&" > D 
    and "&SUBSTITUTE(E7; ","; "."; 1)&" < E"; 0)
```